# How to delete all lines containing a string from all .xml files?

Tags: xml, linux, unix, command-line, terminal

I want to delete all lines containing string "abcfk" from all the .xml files in current directory tree.
I tried `find . -name "*.xml" | xargs sed -i 's/abcfk//g'`

but with this i can only replace..but not deleted the line.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
sed -i '/abcfk/d' $(find . -name "*.xml")
```

note that `s/abcfk//g` will leave empty lines, instead use `/abcfg/d` to delete lines with `abcfg`. Alternatively:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sed -i '/abcfk/d' {} +
```